# MySQL query not executing properly PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT doc
    FROM docs
    WHERE id = '$id';";
    $doctext = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

I'm new to PHP/MySQL and am unsure what is going wrong.  The code above is supposed to get the id from the URL, which works fine, then select the `doc`--which is a column of data adjacent to the `id` column--from the table `docs` which matches the given `$id` value.

However, instead it just returns "Resource id #11", which makes me think that I'm mixing up the `SELECT`, `FROM`, and `WHERE` keywords somehow, because it's not giving an error, just the wrong data.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Also, have you read *any* documentation on how to retrieve results using `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: How does your title relate to your question?

Comment: @Matt well do you know the answer?  Ofc I'm reading up on PHP/MySQL documentation... just happens to be my 2nd day writing anything including a <?php tag.

Comment: Yes, I know the answer. However the *reason* I know the answer is because I picked up books & read articles. I *did not* rely on others to coddle me.

Comment: Didn't know I couldn't use SE in conjunction with books and articles.  My bad bro.

Comment: @Hubrid sorry I sound angry there; it's the end of the work-day for me. My point is that SE shouldn't be your *first* source. I reacted a bit harshly, but you should also note what steps you took to try to resolve your problem and why you think they didn't work. I wish you the best in your new endeavor. Lusitanian provided a good answer, BTW.

Comment: @Matt Sorry you had a rough work-day.  I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Hubrid He (rightly) questions whether you've looked at the documentation because a) there is a giant red warning not to use `mysql_*` functions, and b) there is a very simple example in the docs. It just seems, to me anyway, that it would be hard to walk away from that documentation page without having any idea why this code is failing. So all that said.... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php With all due respect, please read the manual.

Comment: I've been reading over w3schools and books so that'd be why Chris.

Comment: @Hubrid w3Schools is not accurate at all. It is important to understand that third-party sites will **never** be a better source than the vendor itself. For javascript or HTML, look at MDN or the spec, for PHP look at php.net. Now that you know, there shouldn't be any question left: check out the **real** documentation and move on. It isn't personal. (accept an answer, while you're at it! :D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is executing fine. Your issue is that you aren't retrieving any data from the result. The `mysql_query` function doesn't automatically retrieve data, you retrieve it in a format you desire using one of the `mysql_fetch` functions like [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).
 Note that you really shouldn't be using the ancient MySQL api, and should be using PDO (or MySQL). Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and you should use bound parameters, a feature of MySQLi and PDO.

Answer (score 3):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT doc FROM docs WHERE id = :id');

$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Hubrid please tend to use `PDO` and not `mysql_*` functions for the sake of everyone...

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the information provided, I would like to point you in a better direction as your current method is not handling the resultant data properly.  Do not use the mysql extension. Instead, use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) extension. Using one of these alternative extensions will help serve as the first step in preventing SQL injection.

Using PDO:

```
<?php  

/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */ 
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT doc FROM docs WHERE id = ?'); 
$sth->execute(array($_GET['id'])); 
$results = $sth->fetchAll();  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this:

```
<?php
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $query = "SELECT doc
     FROM docs
     WHERE id = '".$id."';";
     $doctext = mysqli_query($query);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT doc
    FROM docs
    WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "';";
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row['doc'];
?>
```

But as suggested, try to port this to `mysqli_*` family of functions as `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated.